# jQuery .remove() Not Working After Valid Selection of Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/coh1xr77/5/

I need to delete an `<LI>` DOM Element correctly selected with a Selector based on its exact content. My list contains a set of Time LI's and my choice is to delete the first one in the list, `12:15am`, based on the exact text match, when I click the button.

I can see that my selection is correct because I'm getting an [Object] reference in the alert box, rather than "Undefined".

However, the subsequent remove() on this element does nothing: the element remains.

```
var myselection = '12:15am';

$('#remove').click(function() {

    var current = $('.ui-timepicker-list li').filter(function() { 
            return $(this).text() ===  myselection;
        });

    alert('current = ' + current);  // This works, element found

    $(current).remove();   // This does nothing (or doesn't remove properly)

});
```

Comment: i mean... it's pretty obvious that "12:15am" is not equal to "12:15am (0 mins)"

Comment: That's inside a SPAN. Are you saying the text() selects the Span content, as well?

Comment: Yes, as documented.

Comment: Then how would I select only the LI inner text?

Comment: Contains would do it.

Comment: I don't think you're right -- if it couldn't find the LI, then the Alert box wouldn't have worked either. Also contains() is unacceptable, I need the exact match (e.g. 1:45 and 11:45 would both fit)

Comment: That's where you are wrong. jQuery filtering/selection methods ALWAYS return a jquery object, regardless of whether or not an element was found. Alert the length of `current` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the condition to check if the `li`'s `innerText` starts with the selected time string. Like: `$(this).text().indexOf(myselection) == 0`

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/coh1xr77/11/

### Update

Considering that all time values have the bracketed relative time strings at the end, you could try splitting based on that bracket `(`, and compare with the first part of that string. Like: `$(this).text().split('(')[0].trim() == myselection`

Here's the fiddle with that: https://jsfiddle.net/coh1xr77/12/

### Update 2

If you are absolutely certain that the structure of `li` elements will not change, you could access the text using the `childNodes`. Like: `$(this)[0].childNodes[0].textContent == myselection;`

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/coh1xr77/14/

Comment: No, it can't be a substring, it must be an exact match. Think about it: if I have "1:45" and "11:45", the indexOf would select both. But I need the EXACT match.

Comment: Good point. You could use `$(this).text().indexOf(myselection) == 0` which means the `li`'s text must **start with** the selection.

Comment: There is also the `String.prototype.startsWith` for all browsers that aren't Internet Explorer.